# How to pass an argument in a function, which will be used as a method name in a web3 instance with web3.js?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will take as argument the name of a contract method with web3.js.
This is the original function:

```
async function estimateGas() {
  const w3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
  window.contract = await new w3.eth.Contract(myContr.abi, myContr.addr);
  window.contract.methods.buy().estimateGas({from: ethereum.selectedAddress});
}
```

THis function works fine like this, but I would like to modifiy it so that I may be able to use all the other methods on the contract  (like for example .claim(), .transfer(), etc) as an argument, like so:

```
async function estimateGas(argumentName) {
  const w3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
  window.contract = await new w3.eth.Contract(myContr.abi, myContr.addr);    
  // I want to change here below what was the ".buy()" method with my argument as if it would have been ".argumentName()"
  window.contract.methods.argumentName().estimateGas({from: ethereum.selectedAddress});
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definetelly do that with Javascript. Take a look at another way to access the properties of a js object, with the `obj["property"]` syntax:

```js
async function estimateGas(argumentName) {
  const w3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
  window.contract = await new w3.eth.Contract(myContr.abi, myContr.addr);    
  // I want to change here below what was the ".buy()" method with my argument as if it would have been ".argumentName()"
  window.contract.methods[argumentName]().estimateGas({from: ethereum.selectedAddress});
}
```

As an example, take a look at this answer where I use this approach to dynamically call a function of a js web3 object: [Is there a way to extract functions from an ABI and show it in the front end?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135214/is-there-a-way-to-extract-functions-from-an-abi-and-show-it-in-the-front-end/135218#135218)

```js
const result = await counter.methods[functionName](...args).call();
```